# Looking for vector data for the country Turkey

Tags: shapefile, data, turkey

Looking for vector data for the country Turkey, specifically roads, railroads, and rivers shapefiles... no cost would be nice, but it needs to be more detailed and accurate than [mapcruzin's free data](http://www.mapcruzin.com/free-turkey-arcgis-maps-shapefiles.htm).

Something under $500 would also be considered.

Anyone here have experience/recommendations with locating low cost shapefile data for Turkey?

Comment: Have you considered OSM? http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/WikiProject_Turkey

Comment: Thanks underdark, i have attempted to extract vector data from openstreetmap but without success... any suggestions on how to extract vector data (shape files) from openstreetmap would be most appreciated.

Comment: You could have a look at http://downloads.cloudmade.com/asia/western_asia/turkey#downloads_breadcrumbs

Comment: Thanks underdark! How long has that http://downloads.cloudmade.com downloads page been available? Truly impressive source!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://download.geofabrik.de/osm/europe/

> `turkey.shp.zip    22-May-2012 05:09   59M ESRI Shapefile (EPSG:4326), zipped`

has Turkey in Shapefile format extracted from the Master database on 22-May-2012.

You can use Quantum GIS (QGIS) to view the files.

Would recommend you load this data into a database postgres with postgis high recommended.

http://postgis.refractions.net/download/

Comment: Wow! another beautiful data source! How long has geofabrik been serving up this wonderful data? Mapperz, underdark, and gisstackexchange Thank You! Truly a wonderful place/people for answers to GIS issues. Size mutluluk dolu yıllar diliyorum!

Comment: Since Early 2008

Comment: how did you get turned on to it, if i may ask? i searched all over the web looking for this vector data.

Comment: http://mapperz.blogspot.com/2008/09/open-street-map-in-shapefile-format.html

Answer (score -1):

You can visit http://download.geofabrik.de/europe.html and download Turkey vector data.